# Unable to add ssh key using ssh-add

Tags: ssh

I have the following file in `~/.ssh` that has my public SSH key:

- authorized_keys

I then run the following and add my passphrase and get no errors or warnings:

```
$ ssh-add ~/.ssh/authorized_keys
```

When I try to list the fingerprints I get:

```
$ ssh-add -l
> The agent has no identities.
```

When I re-run `ssh-add` and follow up with `echo $?` it returns an exit code of `1` meaning a failure occurred. [This documentation](https://www.eldos.com/documentation/sbb/documentation/ref_err_ssherrorcodes.html) says that code 1 means the error was caused by:

```
Invalid identification string of SSH-protocol
```

What does this mean exactly, and how do I resolve it?

Answer (score 1):

`ssh-add` loads **private** keys, not **public** keys. From `man ssh-add`:

```
DESCRIPTION
     ssh-add adds private key identities to the authentication agent, ssh-agent(1).  When run without arguments, it adds
     the files ~/.ssh/id_rsa, ~/.ssh/id_dsa, ~/.ssh/id_ecdsa, ~/.ssh/id_ed25519 and ~/.ssh/identity.  After loading a
     private key, ssh-add will try to load corresponding certificate information from the filename obtained by appending
     -cert.pub to the name of the private key file.  Alternative file names can be given on the command line.
```

Try to run it without arguments.